# Getting pointer's initialization of defined structs as global variables

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, network-programming

I wanna reserve memory for different  header struct pointers in order to fill it, as follow:

```
struct  icmp      *_icmp_hdr = (struct icmp *) Smalloc(hs_icmp, 0);   
struct  icmp6_hdr *_icmp6 = (struct icmp6_hdr *) Smalloc(hs_icmp6, 0);
struct  ip        *_ip_hdr = (struct ip *) Smalloc(hs_ip, 0);
struct  ip6_hdr   *_ip6_hdr = (struct ip6_hdr *) Smalloc(hs_ip6, 0);
union   data_err  *_payload = (union data_err *) Smalloc(s_payload, 0);
```

The problem comes when the size of header structs as: `struct icmp, icmp6_hdr, ip...`

1. I've defined as it's shown, this size for every structure (eg. `hs_icmp, hs_icmp6, hs_ip, ...`) using `sizeof()` operator (eg.`#define hs_icmp sizeof(struct icmp)`).

When i compile i get an error for every header struct pointer and i don't know how to solve it, eg:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
struct icmp    *_icmp_hdr = (struct icmp *) Smalloc(hs_icmp, 0);
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a function call as part of the initializer expression for global variables.

This is what what the error message is telling you.

The size of the structs has nothing to do with it (and a structure can't have size 0, really).

Comment: This is a fine comment (and I am guessing the same) but I am not sure it's a great answer.

Comment: Yep, exactly, i've declare them as global variables. So is there the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize global variables with non-constant expressions. For example you cannot do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0;
int b = a; //error: initializer element is not constant
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

but you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0;
int main(void) {
    int b = a; //OK
    return 0;
}
```

or this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 0
int b = A; //OK
int main(void) {        
    return 0;
}
```